# Django new extended user profile after users have registered

Tags: django-models

I have extended user model in Django. All works great. After few months I want to create a new model(profile2) that would have same users populated as in profile1. How do I easily migrate users to it?

```
class profile1(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    prfile_progress = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(blank = True, null=True)
    finish_time = models.DateTimeField(blank = True, null=True)
    
##This will be created after some users have already registered. 
class profile2(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    prfile_progress = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(blank = True, null=True)
    finish_time = models.DateTimeField(blank = True, null=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        profile1.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile1.save()
```

when I migrate and run the app I get LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM as there is no data in the DB

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 options:

1. adjust migration file and create user when you migrate
2. access DB to create the users in SQL- this looked easies so I just ran INSERT statements in DB to generate the missing users